# What does this FTP command really do?

Tags: files, ftp, man

I am currently learning UNIX and I am exploring FTP and how it works. I try to understand what this FTP command is doing:

```
echo Start FTP

      ftp -nv 10.232.164.17 3147 << _EOF
        user lenox lenox
        ascii
        prompt
        lcd /usr/tmp/
        get Customers.txt
        get Products.txt
        get Invoices.txt
        get Inventory.txt
                get Demand.txt
        bye
_EOF

          echo Done with FTP Get
```

I get it that it's connecting via the IP address to do the FTP, but that's about it.

Comment: That looks like a expect script ?

Comment: lcd changes the current ftp process ie your client's current directory, while 'cd' moves about in the remote hierarchy.  ascii: ftp can be instructed to fetch as binary or ascii.

Answer (score 1):

The script fetches five text files from the FTP server running at 10.232.164.17, on port 3147.  It store all files in the local directory `/usr/tmp`.  That's about it.

The individual FTP commands, like `get`, `lcd` etc. are documented in the `ftp` manual on your system (see `man ftp`).